# Settings and configurations of chat bot app in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to create a Microsoft Teams chatbot app for a self-hosted service. Each customer will different settings and configurations. These are basic configurations

1. URL
2. Token

One app needs to be usable to multiple organizations. When they install it, their URL where the solution lives is an integral part of the app's configuration to connect with it. How do we configure such a setting inside the chat app after the installation? Or Is it possible to configure the settings when installing the chat bot? I see some sample apps but i couldn't see the examples to set the configurations like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "URL" and "Token" in this regard - please explain

Comment: For example, this can be hosted on any URL ( say customservice.theirbusinessname.com ) and this URL will be different for each organization. So, we need to make this configurable.

Comment: It's not possible to change the bot URL based on the tenant. This is by design. You can install it to multiple tenant organization by approving it in Application registration in Azure. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Rama-MSFT comments

It's not possible to change the bot URL based on the tenant. This is by design. You can install it to multiple tenant organization by approving it in Application registration in Azure. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).